# $2023$-esque numbers in other bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

$2023$ is the smallest nontrivial positive integer (that is, not $1$) in base $10$ that has the property that the sum of its digits times the square of the sum of the squares of its digits is itself (that is, $(2 + 0 + 2 + 3) \cdot (2^2 + 0^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)^2 = 2023$. What is a general way to find the smallest such nontrivial positive integer for any base?

Base $2.$ No such nontrivial positive integer exists.

Comment: Reference for the $2023$ fact: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119200/happy-2023-to-all

Comment: What method was used to deduce this and check that it is the only one?

Comment: I have no idea. I just found a suitable link.

Comment: The claim of "only nontrivial positive solution in base 10" is not true. There are other solutions, like 2400. One approach is to bound the number of digits ($k$) with $b^{k-1} \leq (b-1)^3k^5$ and then do an exhaustive search.

Comment: Lesson learned: always check your references.

Comment: @mathlander In fact, your reference even stated more solutions. lol.

Comment: It said "happy numbers," and I thought that those were the ones with the greater-than property.

Comment: $9801$ is happy in bases $7$ and $9$ (its representations are $40401_7$ and $14400_9$).